# How to design a circuit that cycles

Tags: circuit-design, karnaugh-map

I want to design a digital circuit that transitions in the following sequence as follows:
(0,0,0,0) -> (0,1,0,1) -> (0,0,0,0) -> (1,0,1,0)

How would I go about making a k-map for this?  Should I add another variable, so that it looks like something I have below?

(0,0,0,0,0) -> (0,0,1,0,1) -> (1,0,0,0,0) -> (0,1,0,1,0)

I have tried making an ordinary k-map of 4 variables, but since there are two output values for (0,0,0,0), I have not had any luck.

Comment: Karnaugh maps are not useful for sequential logic, unless I'm vastly misunderstanding their use (I mostly deal with power and analog stuff, so not the most well-versed in this). I'd suggest looking into finite state machines; that seems like the better way to analyze this.

Comment: What kind of technology are you going to implement this in? Discrete logic? FPGA? CPLD?

Comment: There are four states. Maybe just create a two bit counter and feed the count into some logic gates. Register the outputs with D flip-flops to avoid transient states and hazards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to use a D-flop with \$Q\$ and \$\overline{Q}\$, but they don't include one in this editor. So I can't feed back \$\overline{Q}\$ to the input on that device. Oh, well. So try:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXs7Gj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where { A, B, C, D } is the output state. No glitch considerations here. Just idealized. Offering this only to get you thinking creatively.

Comment: How are you getting 4 states with one flip-flop? `A` should go 0, 0, 0, 1; not 0, 1, 0, 1, ....

Comment: @ThePhoton I'm cheating! I use the clock LOW to disable all outputs (that's two states) and clock HIGH to enable either one or the other AND gate to get the other two. It's silly. But I'm trying to get the OP to let loose and think creatively. (It also simulates fine with Logisim using the D-flop.) So state 0 is on the first clock LO, state 1 is on clock HI, state 2 is on next clock LO, state 3 is on following clock HI.

Comment: Next lesson: logic glitches.

Comment: @ThePhoton Yeah. Already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

A few hints:

1. Your first and third outputs are always the same. So there's no need to calculate them separately. Just connect whatever needs to be driven by the third output to the same logic that generates the first output. If there is a substantial load current, you might need buffers to provide it.

   Same goes for the second and fourth outputs.
2. You have 4 states, but you can encode them in various ways. One obvious way is to make the state machine with a two bit counter and use a couple of gates to decode the outputs.

   But it might be even simpler to use a *one-hot* encoding (google it for more details) using 4 flip-flops. Then you'll find that each of your outputs happens to be equal to the output of one of the flip flops holding the state. A one-hot state machine for this case (simple sequence of 4 states) can be implemented with a shift register (a single IC if you're doing discrete logic), provided you can arrange to reset it into a state you choose.